# AppleScript: QuickTime movie recording automatic save after it's finished recording

Tags: timestamp, applescript, filenames, quicktime, autosave

I am trying to write a small AppleScript for a project where I have to:

- Start a QuickTime movie recording
- minimize the window of the recording
- open a movie that will put itself in full screen
- once the movie is finished playing, the recording should stop
- the recording should save itself IN THE BACKGROUND with filename "current date and time"
- close the movie that was playing
- open a website in Safari.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
set theDate to current date
set filePath to (path to desktop as text)

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set newMovieRecording to new movie recording

    tell newMovieRecording
        start
        tell application "QuickTime Player"
            set miniaturized of window 1 to true
        end tell
        tell application "QuickTime Player"
            open file "Users:test:Desktop:Movie.m4v"
            tell document "Movie.m4v" to play

            set the bounds of the first window to {0, 0, 1800, 1100} -- I did not find how to put the window in full screen (whatever the screen size is: I wrote this script on an external screen , but the project will take place on the screen of a laptop).
        end tell
        delay 160 -- the length of the movie
        save newMovieRecording in file (filePath) & theDate
        stop
        close newMovieRecording

        tell application "QuickTime Player"
            close document "Movie.m4v"
        end tell

    end tell
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "http://stackoverflow.com"
end tell
```

The above script is as far as I could get: When the movie recording is supposed to save itself, I get the following message from AppleScript Editor: "AppleScript Error - QuickTime Player got an error: Invalid key form."

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use `present` to play your movie fullscreen (instead of `play`.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems there.

1. “file (filePath) & theDate” is likely to be “file (file path)” and then a date added onto it, which will fail as they can’t be concatenated. To fix this, create the file path before saving, something like:

   set fileName to filePath & theDate
   save newMovieRecording in file fileName
2. However, there’s another problem: the default date format contains colons, which can’t be in used in Mac OS X filepaths. You’ll probably want to construct a date/time stamp without colons, something like:

   set dateStamp to the year of theDate & "-" & the month of theDate & "-" & the day of theDate & " " & hours of theDate & "-" & minutes of theDate
3. And the filename has to end in the correct extension or you’ll get a permission denied error:

   set fileName to filePath & dateStamp & ".m4v"

(Note that I used .mov for testing, hopefully they act the same.)